# Application not responding error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I have a tracking app that does tracking based on gps and cell id at every 2 minutes. I have started a service from MainActivity using setRepeting() of AlarmManager. Then inside that service I have written an asynctask.In onPreExecute() I fetch latitude and longitude using gps or cellid. And in doInBackground() i am fetching data from sqlite db and send to server. Even after writing all network related code in asynctask app sometimes says application not responding. and on pressing ok it restart. What can I do to avoid this.

```
public class SendDataAsync extends Service {
Logger logger ;
Context con;
String level1;

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in onReceive of GPSLoggerService",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", 100);
        level1 = String.valueOf(level * 100 / scale);
    }
}; // battery level

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
    logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator + "logs"+ File.separator + "log4j.txt");

    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%d %-5p [%c{2}]-[%L] %m%n");
    logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
    logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
    logConfigurator.configure();
    logger = Logger.getLogger(SendDataAsync.class);
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    FetchCordinates fetchCordinates = new FetchCordinates();
    fetchCordinates.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        logger.info(e);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

FetchCordinates

```
public class FetchCordinates extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Timer monitoringTimer = null;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
    private LocationManager locManager;     

    private static final int gpsMinTime = 1000;
    private static final int gpsMinDistance = 1;
    private double latitude = 0.0;
    private double longitude = 0.0;
    private double altitude = 0.0;
    float mps;
    float kmh;
    SendDataAsync sda;
    Runtime runtime1;
    Process proc1;
    int returnVal1 = 0;
    int data_mode = 0;
    int myLatitude, myLongitude;
    String imeiCellID, datetimeCellID;
    String latitude_cellID, longitude_cellID;
    public String gpslatitude = null;
    public String gpslongitude = null;
    public String gpsaltitude = null;
    private String speed = null;
    private String datetime = null;
    private String imeino = null;
    private String datatype = null;

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;
    DBAdapter db;
    int flag;
    Context context;
    boolean didFindLocation = false;
    long id;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "bp";

    public LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        data_mode = settings.getInt("data_mode", 1);
        startLoggingService();
        startMonitoringTimer();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            sendData();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.info(e.toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.info(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    protected void removeGps()
 {
     locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
 }

 private void startLoggingService() {
        db = new DBAdapter(SendDataAsync.this);
        if (locManager == null) {
            locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        //ma = new MainActivity();

        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        final String bestProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, gpsMinTime,
                    gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
            startTimer();
        } else {
            final List<String> providers = locManager.getProviders(true);

            for (final String provider : providers) {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, gpsMinTime,
                        gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }

 private void startTimer() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000L, 1000L) {// 15 seconds max
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (didFindLocation) {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (!didFindLocation) {
                    removeGps();
                      if(data_mode==1)
                      {
                          monitoringTimer.cancel();
                         cellID(); 
                      }
                      else { 
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext
                      (),"GPS : Cant find Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }

                    stopLoggingService();

                }//if
            }//inFin
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
 // class  location listener
 private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
 {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            didFindLocation = true;
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            altitude = location.getAltitude();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lat :"+latitude+"longi :"+longitude,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            gpsaltitude = String.valueOf(altitude);
            gpslatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
            gpslongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
            mps = location.getSpeed();
            kmh = (float) (mps * 3.6);
            speed = Float.toString(kmh);

            SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            datetime = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(location.getTime()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onProviderDisabled().");
            logger.info("onLocationChanged, ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onProviderEnabled().");
            logger.info("onProviderEnabled, ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onStatusChanged().");
            logger.info("onStatusChanged, ");
        }
  };    

  public void saveData() {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            imeino = tm.getDeviceId();

             DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(SendDataAsync.this);

            setFlag();      
            datatype = String.valueOf(flag);
            // --add contact----

            db.open();

            id = db.insertData(imeino, gpslatitude, gpslongitude, datetime,
                    gpsaltitude, speed, level1, datatype, "1");
            db.close();
    }// end of saveData() function

  private void startMonitoringTimer() {
        monitoringTimer = new Timer();
        monitoringTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                if (longitude != 0.0 && latitude != 0.0) {

                    monitoringTimer.cancel();
                    monitoringTimer = null;
                    // turnGPSOn();
                    //didFindLocation=false;
                    saveData();
                    removeGps();                        
                    stopLoggingService();
                }
            }
        },TIMER_DELAY,TIMER_DELAY);
    }

  public boolean isInternetOn() {
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        } else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public int setFlag() {
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean firstRecord = settings.getBoolean("firstRecord", false);
        boolean firstRecordAfterBoot = settings.getBoolean("justBooted", false);

        if (firstRecord == true) {
            flag = 0;
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"1st record after installation : "+flag,Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            // ).show();
            settings.edit().putBoolean("firstRecord", false).commit();
        } else if (firstRecordAfterBoot == true) {
            flag = 1;
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"1st record after boot : "+flag,Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            // ).show();
            settings.edit().putBoolean("justBooted", false).commit();
        } else {
            flag = 2;
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"regular : "+flag,Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            // ).show();
        }
        return flag;

    }

    public void cellID() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager
                .getCellLocation();
        int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
        int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        datetimeCellID = sdfDateTime.format(new Date());
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"cellid="+cell_Id+"\nGsm Location Area Code:"+gsm_Loc_Area_Code,Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        // ).show();

        CellidAsync cellasy=new CellidAsync();
        String pass = null;
        try {
            pass = cellasy.execute(cid,lac).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] arr=pass.split(",");

        if (Boolean.valueOf(arr[0])) {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            imeiCellID = tm.getDeviceId();
            myLatitude=Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
            myLongitude=Integer.valueOf(arr[2]);
            latitude_cellID = String.valueOf((float) myLatitude / 1000000);
            longitude_cellID = String.valueOf((float) myLongitude / 1000000);
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lat:"+latitude_cellID+"Long:"+longitude_cellID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            // ).show();
            // DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);

            // --add contact----
            db.open();
            setFlag();
            datatype = String.valueOf(flag);
            id = db.insertData(imeiCellID, latitude_cellID, longitude_cellID,
                    datetimeCellID, "null", "null", level1, datatype, "0");
            db.close();

            // --get all contacts----------
            /*db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllData();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //DisplayData(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();*/

        }// if
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CellID : Can't find Location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }// else

    }// cellID



    public void sendData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in sendData", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enableInternet();
        setAirplaneMode();
        runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
        proc1 = runtime1.exec("ping -c 1 some ip");

        try {
            returnVal1 = proc1.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean reachable1 = (returnVal1==0);
        if(reachable1==true)
        {

        if(isInternetOn())
        {

            JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                //DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
                db.open();
                Cursor cursor=db.getAllData();
                if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        jObject = new JSONObject();
                        jObject.put("Imei", cursor.getString(1));
                        jObject.put("Lat", cursor.getString(2));
                        jObject.put("Long", cursor.getString(3));
                        jObject.put("Gpsdatetime", cursor.getString(4));
                        jObject.put("Altitude",cursor.getString(5));
                        jObject.put("Speed", cursor.getString(6));
                        jObject.put("Battery", cursor.getString(7));
                        jObject.put("DataType", cursor.getString(8));
                        jObject.put("DataSource", cursor.getString(9));

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        String dt=cursor.getString(4).replace(" ","*");


                        String datatoServer=cursor.getString(1)+","+cursor.getString(2)+","+cursor.getString(3)+","+dt+","+cursor.getString(5)+","+cursor.getString(6)+","+cursor.getString(7)+","+cursor.getString(8)+","+cursor.getString(9);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datatoServer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            HttpEntity entity1;
                            HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            String url1 ="http:/url="+datatoServer;
                            HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost(url1);
                            StringEntity se1 = new StringEntity(datatoServer);
                            se1.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                            se1.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                            "application/json"));
                            entity1 = se1;
                            //request1.setEntity(entity1);
                            HttpResponse response1 = client1.execute(request1);
                            entity1 = response1.getEntity();

                        //----------------------------------------------------------------

                        db.deleteContacts(cursor.getLong(0));
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }//if
                db.close();                     
            }//try
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.info(""+e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                logger.info(""+e);
            }
        }//if
        }//if ping
    }  //method 

    public void setAirplaneMode()
    {
        // Check for Airplane Mode
        boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0) == 1;

       if (isEnabled) {
            // toggle airplane mode
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
            // Post an intent to reload
            Intent intent = new Intent(                 

Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
       }
    }

    public void enableInternet()
    {       
        try{
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            boolean isEnabled;
            if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == 

TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
                //Toast.makeText(GPSLoggerService.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isEnabled = true;
            }else{
                //Toast.makeText(GPSLoggerService.this, "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isEnabled = false;  
            }   
    if (isEnabled) {
    } else {
        ConnectivityManager dataManager;
        dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod

("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true);    
    }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.info(""+e);
        }
}//enable internet


}//async
private void stopLoggingService() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver);
    stopSelf();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: wait i ll edit my code

Comment: i have posted my service code

Answer (score 0):

You should be fetching the lat and long in the doInBackground() method, and not in preExecute().

Fetching the location might take some time, and should be done in the background. That is why you have this problem.

Comment: ok. but it will take all my code in doInBackground. Is it feasible to write fetching store and sending all code in doInBackground().